# Creating a linkedin webscraper using python

Tags: python, authentication, error-handling, linkedin-api, scraper

I'm using anaconda and trying to create a scraper that can go on linkedin and scrape relevant information from pages. At the moment I'm just looking to get it to login and pull the source code from the relevant page. The code below however keeps returning "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". Does anyone know where this code is going wrong?

```
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
import os
import urllib
import re
import string
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = "user@email.com"
password = "password"

cookie_filename = "parser.cookies.txt"

class LinkedInParser(object):

def __init__(self, login, password):
    """ Start up... """
    self.login = login
    self.password = password

    # Simulate browser with cookies enabled
    self.cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(cookie_filename)
    if os.access(cookie_filename, os.F_OK):
        self.cj.load()
    self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
        urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
        urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
        urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
        urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
    )
    self.opener.addheaders = [
        ('User-agent', ('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; '
                       'Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'))
    ]

    # Login
    self.loginPage()

    title = self.loadTitle()
    print(title)

    self.cj.save()


def loadPage(self, url, data=None):
    """
    Utility function to load HTML from URLs for us with hack to continue despite 404
    """
    # We'll print the url in case of infinite loop
    # print "Loading URL: %s" % url
    try:
        if data is not None:
            response = self.opener.open(url, data)
        else:
            response = self.opener.open(url)
        return ''.join([str(l) for l in response.readlines()])
    except Exception as e:
        # If URL doesn't load for ANY reason, try again...
        # Quick and dirty solution for 404 returns because of network problems
        # However, this could infinite loop if there's an actual problem
        return self.loadPage(url, data)

def loadSoup(self, url, data=None):
    """
    Combine loading of URL, HTML, and parsing with BeautifulSoup
    """
    html = self.loadPage(url, data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
    return soup

def loginPage(self):
    """
    Handle login. This should populate our cookie jar.
    """
    soup = self.loadSoup("https://www.linkedin.com/")
    csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']
    login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'session_key': self.login,
        'session_password': self.password,
        'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
    }).encode('utf8')

    self.loadPage("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit", login_data)
    return

def loadTitle(self):
    soup = self.loadSoup("http://www.linkedin.com/nhome")
    return soup.find("title")

parser = LinkedInParser(username, password)
```

The error message is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-43815804ad91> in <module>()
     87         return soup.find("linked")
     88 
---> 89 parser = LinkedInParser(username, password)

<ipython-input-24-43815804ad91> in __init__(self, login, password)
     34 
     35         # Login
 ---> 36         self.loginPage()
     37 
     38         title = self.loadTitle()

 <ipython-input-24-43815804ad91> in loginPage(self)
     73         """
     74         soup = self.loadSoup("https://www.linkedin.com/")
 ---> 75         csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']
     76         login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({
     77             'session_key': self.login,

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What line is generating the error? Your indentation for the LinkedInParse is wrong, but I don't know if that's a copy-pasting error or not.

Comment: sorry that is a copy paste error. The lines that are marked by the error message are 36, 75 and 89.

Comment: I think it means that soup.find("title") is returning None.

Comment: At least give us a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")
```

isn't returning anything. Most likely, it is simply not finding an object with this specific ID.

Your script is using a cookie jar to accept a cookie from LinkedIn. This cookie is used by LinkedIn to keep your account logged in, so you don't need to log in again. Your `LinkedInParser` object, however, will try to log in every time you create a new instance. It loads the cookie from a file:

```
if os.access(cookie_filename, os.F_OK):
    self.cj.load()
```

However, it does not check whether this cookie is present before trying to log in:

```
# Login
self.loginPage()
```

I'm guessing this is what happened: you ran the script once, it got a cookie. Now you're trying to run it again, it tries to log in again, but when it pulls the LinkedIn main page, there is no login form because you are already logged in. The script can't find the element it's looking for, and you can't get the `['value']` of a non-existing element.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
if not os.access(cookie_filename, os.F_OK):
    self.loginPage()
    self.cj.save()
```